# Help with Database Design for a CRM

Tags: mysql, database-design, table

I am creating a CRM for a call-center and I want to store the input field data in a database.
My problem is that I am quite new to this ordeal and have little - to no idea how to structure my database.

Should I create multiple tables for each part of the form and submit the data there or should everything be submitted to one large table?

Note 1: the form has around 80 fields with the data I need.
Note 2: I also have another form with approximately 50 fields and plan to add another form which will be much small with app. 15 fields.

I appreciate any help and thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Hi, maybe you can group these fields, by update frequency or by main subject. Fundamentally update a 80 fields table is not a problem but your program maintenance tasks will be much more easy by grouping fields

Answer (score 0):

Start with one table for each of those two "forms".

After you have tentative `SELECTs` and "reporting" requirements and volume estimates.  Then we can discuss normalization, many-to-many tables, etc.

Also, learn about EAV schema design and be sure to learn why it is not a panacea.  (Then I won't have to lecture you when you come back.)

There are some examples of CRM in this forum and in stackoverflow.com